# Play 2.2 - Subprojects with multiple databases

Tags: database, playframework, git-submodules, playframework-2.2, subproject

I have a play 2.2.1 application that has a subproject nested inside a /modules/ directory.  I want to define models in the subproject and use a separate database for those models.

My application.conf file is defined like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://user:pw@localhost/default"

db.other.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.other.url="postgres://user:pw@localhost/other"

ebean.default="models.*"
ebean.other="submodule.models.*"
```

When I run this, I get the error message "PersistenceException: Error with [models.SubmoduleModel] It has not been enhanced but it's superClass [class play.db.ebean.Model] is? (You are not allowed to mix enhancement in a single inheritance hierarchy) marker[play.db.ebean.Model] className[models.SubmoduleModel]".

I believe this worked in Play 2.1.4.  Any idea why this doesn't work in Play 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Rumor has it that this will will be fixed in Play 2.4.0. See [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2317).